# GraphDB reasoning makes different inference for Classes

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, reasoning, graphdb

I loaded the following statements in a repo with a ruleset OWL-Horst (Optimized).

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/owlim#> .

:Foo rdf:type owl:Class .
:Bar rdf:type owl:Class . 
:Baz rdf:type owl:Class ;
     rdfs:subClassOf :Bar .
```

If I look at the inferred statements, I notice that for the class `:Foo` there is no inference. Instead there are basic inferred statements for both `:Bar` and `:Baz`. E.g.,:

```
:Bar rdf:type rdfs:Class    
:Bar rdfs:subClassOf :Bar
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

owl-horst-optimised ruleset "do not know" what owl:Class is so you are not getting anyting inferred out of statements relating a resource being rdf:type of owl:Class

The inferences produced are due to the rdfs:domain and rdfs:range of rdfs:subClassOf and its transitivity.

One way to get something inferred is to add "owl:Class rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Class" to the repository.